# Python Code running in Docker not working with NGROK

Tags: python, docker

rather new to coding in general and especially new to docker & python so please excuse any blatant mistakes. I have been struggling with a specific issue for weeks now and maybe someone here can help me.

A webservice we'd like to use needs to be connected to a `PostgreSQL` Database via a Python connector. This connector basically compares data input on the webservice with the data in the DB and matches variables.

https://github.com/rossumai/elis-connector-example-python

Right now I am running the databse in AWS and I have succesfully uploaded sample data on it. Also I have run the connector.py code in Docker via the `localhost:5000` port. Now I want to connect all the parts and I am running Ngrok to tunnel my `localhost:5000` and I tell the webservice to connect to the https address `ngrok` is giving me.

Unfortunately I am receiving the `"Failed to complete tunnel connection: The connection was successfully tunneled but the client failed to establish a connection to localhost:5000"`

Is this a port issue?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /src/connector.py

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc
RUN pip3 install psycopg2~=2.7.7
RUN apt-get autoremove -y gcc
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./connector.py" ]
```

Any help, or what else can I add to make my problem a bit more comprehensible?

BR & thanks for any help

Comment: Typically docker runs inside a virtual machine when you are running it on your local laptop. Can you make sure that the port is mapped inside the machine? You could also try to use ngrok inside the docker container itself.

Comment: Are you running ngrok inside your docker container or on your local machine? If it's the latter, you should first bind the container's port 5000 to your local port 5000.

Comment: I am running ngrok outside of the docker container but locally on my machine. I also exposed the port 5000 in the dockerfile but I am still receive a Bad Gateway error unfortunately.

Comment: I assume that the connector.py is running on port:5000 as the last line of the code is the following: 

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)